# How to use user input to create a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, user-input

I have a data table:

```
sample_data = {'Sample': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                'Surface': ['Top', 'Bottom', 'Top', 'Bottom'],
                'Intensity' : [21, 32, 14, 45]}

sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=sample_data)
```

I would like to add user input to create a column 'Condition' based on the 'Sample' column.  The function below returns the error "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable"

```
def get_choice(df, column):
    for i in column:
        user_input = input('Condition= ')
        df['Condition'] = df(user_input)
    return df

get_choice(sample_dataframe, 'Sample')
```

Comment: It seems weird to me that you pass a string column name and then proceed to iterate over the characters (??). Did you mean to pass `['Sample', ]` instead of `'Sample'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you where trying to add inputs corresponding to elements in sample to a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
sample_data = {'Sample': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                'Surface': ['Top', 'Bottom', 'Top', 'Bottom'],
                'Intensity' : [21, 32, 14, 45]}
sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=sample_data)
def get_choice(df, column):
    user_input=[]
    for i in df[column]:
        print(i)
        user_input.append(input('Condition= '))
    df['Condition'] = user_input
    return df

print(get_choice(sample_dataframe, 'Sample'))
```